# Generate HTML web form from XML configuration file with Perl and vice versa

Tags: html, xml, perl, perl-module

I am in need of assistance with the following problem. There is an application that I co-wrote and currently manage that is written in a combination C and Haskell. The application can be customized and configured via a single XML file. It is a back-end application with no user interface. We have been asked to provide a graphical interface to this application via a web interface. Each configuration option is a form field in the html form like this

```
configuration1  string1
configuration2  string2
etc
etc
```

The graphical front end must be a web form that converts the data the user has entered to an XML file that contains the application settings. When the user saves the form, the changes are written to the XML file. When the user opens the form, the configuration from the XML file is displayed in the HTML form fields.

Our team deals with purely back-end stuff and we know nothing of GUIs and the like. The restriction we have is that the front end must be written in Perl and use the LibXML module to conform with company standards. Our team is purely C and Haskell and this is the first request we have ever received for something like that. I would appreciate any help you can provide. If you can include code examples as elaborate as possible it would be a significant help. We know very little Perl but with a clear enough example we can do it. The team that would normally handle this type of stuff is being restructured and we can't wait as we need to get this interface up as quickly as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: for hiring people, better go to [jobs.perl.org](http://jobs.perl.org)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this yourself. You don't know Perl or web-apps and the restrictions you mention regarding libxml are probably only one of several. Every tiny configuration and typing mistake will take you hours or days to figure out. You'll end up miserable and stressed, and so will the users.

Someone from your web team could produce a simple form with supporting tests and documentation in a day. You can then extend and bug-fix secure in the knowledge you start from a working app.

If you can't get someone in-house, you cold hire a coder, but do everything you can to get it done in-house first. Don't do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To the OP: you did not describe the configuration format properly, an XML fragment would have helped us. As it is you will probably have to modify the solution below to match your format.

I assumed a the following format:

```
<conf>
  <option><name>configuration1</name><value>string1 modified</value></option>
  <option><name>configuration2</name><value>string2 re-modded</value></option>
  <option><name>configuration3</name><value>string3</value></option>
</conf>
```

Code that would process this format would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI qw( -nosticky -utf8 :standard form );
use XML::LibXML;

my $CONF="/web/data/conf.xml"; # or wherever your XML is located

# dispatch table, action => code to process it
my $dispatch= { display => \&display_conf,
                edit    => \&display_edit_form,
                save    => \&save_edits,
              };

# action is "what to do"
my $action= param( 'action') || 'display';

$dispatch->{$action}->() || exit_error( "wrong action");
exit;

# load the XML and build a table to display it
sub display_conf
  { my $conf= XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $CONF);
    my $content;
    foreach my $option ($conf->findnodes( '/conf/option'))
      { $content .= Tr( td( $option->findvalue( './name')), 
                        td( $option->findvalue( './value'))
                      );
      }
    $content= table( $content);
    # add a link to the edit form
    $content .= p( a({ href => url() . '?action=edit' }, 'edit')); 
    output( $content);                
  }

# load the XML and build a form that will let you edit it
sub display_edit_form
  { my $conf= XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $CONF);
    my $content;
    foreach my $option ($conf->findnodes( '/conf/option'))
      { $content .= Tr( td( $option->findvalue( './name')), 
                        td( input( { type => "text", size => 40, 
                                     name => $option->findvalue( 'name'), 
                                     value => $option->findvalue( './value')}
                                 )
                          )
                      );
      }
    $content= table( $content);
    $content= form( { action => url() }, 
                    hidden( { name => 'action', value => 'save', override => 1 }),
                    $content,
                    submit( 'Save'),
                  );
    output( $content);                
  }

# load the XML, go through all options, update the value from the form, 
# save the XML, display it value, from the form
sub save_edits
  { my $conf= XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $CONF);
    foreach my $option ($conf->findnodes( '/conf/option'))
      { my $new_value= param( $option->findvalue( './name'));
        my( $value_node)= $option->findnodes( './value');
        $value_node->removeChildNodes();
        $value_node->appendText( $new_value);
      }
    $conf->toFile( $CONF);
    display_conf();
  }

# placeholder, 
sub exit_error
  { my $message= shift;
    print header(), p($message);
  }

# output subs, load the template, inject the content and output (with header)   

sub output
  { my $content= shift;
    print header(), fill_in_string( template(), content => $content );
  }


sub fill_in_string
  { my( $template, %param)= @_;
    $template=~ s{<<(\w+)>>}{$param{$1}}g;
    return $template;
  }

sub template
  { return join '', <DATA>; }

# template, very simple
__DATA__
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Configuration Editor</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Configuration Editor</h1>
    <h2>Configuration</h2>
      <<content>>
    </h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Deployement: put the code somewhere it can be run as CGI, and make sure `conf.xml` can be read and written by the web server. It's probably better to put it outside of the web tree.

This is in a way prehistorical Perl. CGI is widely considered archaic and there are more modern and fancy options available in Perl. If your configuration is more complex than  a key/value list, if you want to have custom help for each field or if you need to use a more complex template to conform to your company's look'n feel, then web Frameworks like Dancer or Mojolicious would be better suited than the simple solution above.

OTOH it works, and I this is still how I write a lot of small tools, that have a few internal users and don't need much in terms of UI.

To the people who suggested that this is too complex to do for people not familiar with Perl, way to go guys! This is not rocket science. It's the kind of code that gets people to start with Perl, why wouldn't we help with writing it? This is in fact a perfect illustration of [The Reluctant Perl Programmer](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2012/06/the-reluctant-perl-programmer.html).

Comment: I suggested he get someone else to write something that is mostly what he wants and then hack on that. You've generously done that. If you don't know about "my", "__DATA__", CGI.pm, hashrefs etc. then it's not something that you want to do "as quickly as possible".

Comment: @RichardHuxton the thing is, this is how you learn a language. You have something to do, you read the docs and you do it. It takes you longer than if you knew the language, and the code often sucks, but that's mormal. The whole project is pretty simple and Perl is not that hard to pick up.

Comment: Very true. Given time or when you're the only user it's the best way to learn too. It's exactly what I'm doing in the reverse direction from the OP - playing with a couple of small Haskell projects. However, for an external customer who needs something working "as quickly as possible" I'd never dream of using Haskell at the moment - it can take me hours to figure out the equivalent of a missing bracket.